# WP is easy, The client has to learn it, So what do i offer?

Tags: customization

I am ok with Wordpress functionality, but I am still confused with its business model.

After spending some time learning it, I am considering using Wordpress rather than doing everything from scratch as I am used to.

But I see that the client will manage his content through the WP dashboard, so he has to learn Wordpress and I admit that Wordpress is really easy to use. **So what do i offer as a service vendor?**

If the user knows how to deal with the posts and the content, it wouldn't take much time or effort for him to learn about plugins and other stuff and he will be on his own soon,

**So what is my job then? Is my job as a website business just to install and configure wordpress? is it hard for the end user to do that?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about development or administration.

Answer (score 4):

Your job is to **CREATE** the wordpress template or modify it to companies needs. And of course to do that you need to know HTML. CSS, PHP and WordPress inside out. It's not about using it per se but about coding the "backend" so it actually works. If your business model is to use existing free templates then yeah... your services would be useless.

Comment: ok, but the client still can buy a theme. I am not a theme vendor, i see companies offer to just make a wordpress website, the client already can do that.

Comment: what those companies mean by offering to "make a wordpress website" is exaclty: "We will create a unique theme for you that matches your product/company". Sure clients can buy themes but if they want **A UNIQUE** site (and most serious companies of course do) they search for companies that "makes wordpress websites". Times of everyone using the same themes is over. We live in times where people want EXACT theme that EXACTLY matches their needs. That of course goes for everything - themes, plugins, widgets etc. You as a "service vendor" should provide all of those things made CUSTOM for clients